# Change this to use auto_ptr?

Tags: memory, auto-ptr

I have been reading up on the c++ auto_ptr and unique_ptr and stuff and thought to try and use them in a class I am playing with... but I was having trouble getting it to work...

How would I convert these pointers to auto pointers or some equivalent so the deletion of the pointers is handled automatically?

Header - http://ideone.com/Z9bc5
Body - http://ideone.com/WfwBY

At the moment it is working using normal pointers but I sometimes get a access violation error. I am pretty sure I know what it causing it.. but the "best" way might be to use the automatic deletion stuff recently added to c++11?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `auto_ptr`. Try one of `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. [Here's](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_103/) Sutter explaining when to use which:

> When in doubt, prefer unique_ptr by default, and you can always later move-convert to shared_ptr if you need it. If you know from the start you need shared ownership, however, go directly to shared_ptr via make_shared (see #2 below).

Also from his blog-post:

> **3. What’s the deal with auto_ptr?**
>
> auto_ptr is most charitably characterized as a valiant attempt to
>   create a unique_ptr before C++ had move semantics.
>
> auto_ptr is now deprecated, and should not be used in new code. When
>   you get a chance, try doing a global search-and-replace of auto_ptr to
>   unique_ptr in your code base; the vast majority of uses will work the
>   same, and it might expose (as a compile-time error) or fix (silently)
>   a bug or two you didn’t know you had.

So, your member declarations change from:

```
 sf::Texture * tSpriteSheet;
```

to:

```
 std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> tSpriteSheet;
```

As for member functions which return a raw pointer you have but the obvious choice: You cannot return a `unique_ptr` if the class is not movable. So, you can either:

- Keep the signature as-is
- Return a `const& unique_ptr<T>`
- Return a reference to the object

Choose the one that suits your needs the best.